# Django MessageMiddleware failure

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-settings, django-middleware

I'm using Django 1.5.1 in virtualenv, Python 2.7 on OS X 10.8.4. I changed from `DEBUG = True` to `DEBUG = False` in my Django settings and I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/kilroy/.virtualenvs/project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/kilroy/.virtualenvs/project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/kilroy/.virtualenvs/project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 224, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/Users/kilroy/Sites/PYTHON/project_name/apps/common/views.py", line 436, in handler_500
    messages.error(request, '500 - Internal server error.')
  File "/Users/kilroy/.virtualenvs/project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/api.py", line 102, in error
    fail_silently=fail_silently)
  File "/Users/kilroy/.virtualenvs/project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/api.py", line 22, in add_message
    raise MessageFailure('You cannot add messages without installing '
MessageFailure: You cannot add messages without installing django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware
```

I'm using different settings file for development and production, and on my development machine I set environment variable in `/Users/kilroy/.virtualenvs/project_name/bin/postactivate` file like this:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project_name.settings.local
```

My `base.py` file looks like this https://dpaste.de/avXmL/, and my `local.py` settings like this https://dpaste.de/Z0PXv/.

Why is this happening when I want to disable debugging and how can I trace why this problem occurs in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same stack trace when I set DEBUG false when using the development server. In my case it was related to the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting / check by Django. The symptoms were confusing because a SuspiciousOperation exception was being raised which caused the error.

If I had `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']` in my settings file and `http://localhost:8000` as my browser address all was well. However, if I use the IP address `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` directly I got this error.

Comment: Including ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost'] solved it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this on shell:

```
from django.conf import settings
print settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES
```

And if you don't see `django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware` in middleware_classes you should add it.

I guess you didn't get any 500 error while in development and so this line using `messages.error(request, '500 - Internal server error.')` was never executed and so you did not face this problem in DEBUG=True.

Comment: When in my virtualenv, my python conssole outputs this: `('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')` when I do `print settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`. Yeah, could be that I never got error 500 while in development =) I'm completely confused at the moment how to solve this problem -.-

Comment: This error shouldn't be there then, I am confused as well. What is your settings.MESSAGE_STORAGE, also what version of Django are you on?

Comment: `print settings.MESSAGE_STORAGE` outputs `django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage`. Django version 1.5.1.

Comment: Are you making any modification to `request` in the view? Can you try printing `request._messages` in the view.

Comment: Hm, when I put `print request._messages` in this `handler_500` function, I get a different error: `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute '_messages'`.

Comment: That means `process_request` of MessageMiddleware is not running and your error is raised even before it. Not sure, how I can go ahead hereafter on this bug. What you can try is remove your custom handler for now and let the site tell you the exact error.

Comment: When I remove that handler, I can only see text `Server Error (500)` in browser and nothing is printed out regarding the error in terminal. Could this happen because of improper handling of `request.POST`? Hm, well then, wish me luck in finding the problem -.-

Comment: Yeah possible because of improper handling of request.POST